# platformer game has a 'str' object has no attribute 'get_image' sprite error and I have no idea why

Tags: python, pygame

So, I'm making a sort of sonic type game, and I want him to just display there on the surface kinda floating around until I have an idea of how to make him do collisions and running around (then after that make it a good sonic type game with speed rewards, levels, etc) and I have no idea what is wrong with my code, I have tried changing the sequence of my Player class and the sprite class. I have played around with it for a good solid 2 hours and want to figure why its syntaxing.

> 'str' object has no attribute 'get_image'
>
> File, line 103, in main, playerOne = Player(3, 20, 29, 39)

```
import pygame
import random
import sys

WINDOWWIDTH = 800
WINDOWHEIGHT = 600
WINDOWSIZE = [WINDOWWIDTH,WINDOWHEIGHT]

WHITE = (255,255,255)
RED = (255,0,0)
GREEN = (0,255,0)
BLUE = (0,0,255)

COLORS = [WHITE,RED,GREEN,BLUE]

FPS = 30

#Classes Go Here
class SpriteSheet(object):

   def __init__(self, file_name):

       self.sprite_sheet = pygame.image.load(file_name).convert()

   def get_image(self, x, y, width, height, colorkey):

       image = pygame.Surface([width, height]).convert()
       image.blit(self.sprite_sheet, (0,0), (x,y, width, height))
       image.set_colorkey(colorkey)
       return image

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):

        super().__init__()

        #Sprite
        self.color_key = (72, 98, 78)
        sprite_sheet = 'spritesheet.png'
        self.image = sprite_sheet.get_image(x, y, width, height, self.color_key)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        # Location
        self.rect.x = 10
        self.rect.y = 100
        # Velocity
        self.change_x = 0
        self.change_y = 0

    def update(self):
        self.rect.x += self.change_x
        self.rect.y += self.change_y

def main():
    global COLORS, WINDOWSIZE, DISPLAYSURF, FPSCLOCK
    pygame.init()
    DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode(WINDOWSIZE)
    FPSCLOCK = pygame.time.Clock()
    #Initializations go here
    playerOne = Player(3, 20, 29, 39)
    active_sprite_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
    active_sprite_list.add(playerOne)
    while True:
        #Controls go here
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    playerOne.change_x += 50
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    playerOne.change_x -= 50
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    playerOne.change_y -= 50
                if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    playerOne.change_y += 50
            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    playerOne.change_x = 0
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    playerOne.change_x = 0
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    playerOne.change_y = 0
                if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    playerOne.change_y = 0
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                quit()



        DISPLAYSURF.fill(BLACK)

        #Game Logic goes here
        #Drawing new objects go here
        active_sprite_list.draw(DISPLAYSURF)
        FPSCLOCK.tick(FPS)
        pygame.display.flip()


#Additional Modules go here

def quit():
    pygame.quit()
    sys.exit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: `sprite_sheet` is currently a string object with a value of `'spritesheet.png'`. You are in essence try to perform `'spritesheet.png'.get_image(x, y, width, height, self.color_key)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer to my comment for more details.

Change:

```
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):

        super().__init__()

        #Sprite
        self.color_key = (72, 98, 78)
        sprite_sheet = 'spritesheet.png'
        self.image = sprite_sheet.get_image(x, y, width, height, self.color_key)
```

To:

```
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):

        super().__init__()

        #Sprite
        self.color_key = (72, 98, 78)
        sprite_sheet = SpriteSheet('spritesheet.png') # instantiate the class!
        self.image = sprite_sheet.get_image(x, y, width, height, self.color_key)
```

Comment: Also, spritesheet should be a persistent value (self.sprite_sheet) just to be easier later

Comment: @Pygasm Potentially, I leave that to the game developer to determine if they are ever going to use it again. I'm not familiar with these libraries, just the way the errors occur!

Comment: Ah, Im just saying, if there are several animations, then you might want to get images at different times (or just use a dictionary)

Comment: @Pygasm Yea, again I am not familiar with the libraries or the intent of the program.